# What does this (Unity) NavMesh gizmo mean? (Reddish pixels in front of Agent)

Tags: unity, navmesh

Basically question. I've never seen this gizmo before. Though something I know is that my agent is failing at what's supposed to be doing. So, perhaps an error gizmo? But what kind of error?

[image]

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps needed to reproduce this display, starting from a new, empty scene?

Answer (score 0):

Part of me thinks this might be the gizmo for an Obstacle. Which is when you have an object that you want to move around that effects the shape of your Navmesh dynamically (So it updates the Navmesh as the obstacle moves through it) So you could have something like a moving door that opened and shut. I think there is an option in the Inspector to turn this on / off somewhere. But yes as DMGregory stated, would be really useful to have the steps leading up to this, to be able to advise properly.